# Python pickle module documentation, is a little bit misleading?

Tags: python, pickle

The python docs say:
pickle can save and restore class instances transparently, however the class definition must be importable and live in the same module as when the object was stored.
Could I put a pickler/unpickler in the module where the class was stored?
Or do I have to put the class in the module? And how?
I'm trying to pickle/unpickle a object from a class in a external module.

Comment: Pickling classes at all is normally a bad idea. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Could you include a tangible example? Plus what frb says, generally it's a bad idea to pickle classes. You're better off using a native data type and include methods in your class to save/dump/serialize and restore/load/deserialize that object. This way you separate your data storage and data access.

Comment: I'm pickling objects with classes OUT of the main program.

Comment: @frb: Why is pickling instances a bad idea? Pickle is one of the few formats that can handle arbitrary custom classes; the ZODB (used in Zope, Plone, Pyramid, other areas) relies on that property. It's a honking great idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I admit it's a very opinionated thing to say, but I find that in most programs where the author is using `pickle` (especially on classes) it is really unnecessary and other methods would make more sense.

Comment: @frb: I quite agree, often pickle is the wrong tool, sometimes a dangerous tool, and JSON or XML or what-have-you would be a better choice. But for persisting arbitrary classes it excels. It has it's uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pickle any python class instance, as long as the `pickle` module can import it again when you load the pickle.

It doesn't matter where in your python code you use `load()` or `dump()`, it only matters if the data that you are going to pickle can be retrieved again later on, by importing them from the same location.

So, if you have a module `foo.bar` with a class `Spam` in it, then as long as you can do `from foo.bar import Spam` you can pickle instances of that class, because `pickle` can later on load that class again from the same module.